# How to explain usages of square brackets ([]) operator in EL expressions

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, el, jsp-tags

When I read [**Spring PetClinic**](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-petclinic/) sample application, I found they always put the *add* and *modify* functionalities into a single JSP file, and they use `${owner['new']}` expression to customize elements on current page, for example *"**New** Owner"* or *"Owner"* for a label.

**Are there any other usages of `[]` operator in JSP (Spring) environment?**

The Controller file has the following snippet:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/owners/new", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String initCreationForm(Map<String, Object> model) {
    Owner owner = new Owner();
    model.put("owner", owner);
    return "owners/createOrUpdateOwnerForm";
}
@RequestMapping(value = "/owners/{ownerId}/edit", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String initUpdateOwnerForm(@PathVariable("ownerId") int ownerId, Model model) {
    Owner owner = this.clinicService.findOwnerById(ownerId);
    model.addAttribute(owner);
    return "owners/createOrUpdateOwnerForm";
}
```

The JSP file has the following snippet:

```
<h2>
    <c:if test="${owner['new']}">New </c:if> Owner
</h2>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `[]` will allow you to:

#### Get a property, if the object is a bean (has getters and setters):

```
${car['type']}
```

This will be equivalent to `car.getType();` (or `car.isType()` if the `type` field is a `boolean`).

#### Get a key's value, if the object is a `Map`:

```
${carMap['Volvo']}
```

This will be equivalent to `carMap.get('Volvo');` when `carMap` is a `Map`.

#### Get an index, if the object is an `array` or `List`:

```
${cars[1]}
```

This is equivalent to `cars[1]` if `cars` is an `array` or equivalent to `cars.get(1)` if `cars` is a `List`.

More details/source: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnahu.html

---

**Edit:**

Your question's expression (`${owner['new']}`) falls into the first case. In the petclinick app, the [`Owner`](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-petclinic/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/samples/petclinic/model/Owner.java) class is a subclass of [`Person`](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-petclinic/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/samples/petclinic/model/Person.java) which is a subclass of [`BaseEntity`](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-petclinic/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/samples/petclinic/model/BaseEntity.java). And `BaseEntity` has a method `isNew()` (so `Owner` has that method as well).

This way the snippet `${owner['new']}` is equivalent to `owner.isNew()`.

Comment: thanks for your reply, but 'new' is a java keyword , it can't be the situation you listed!

Comment: I see what's your point. In that scenario, `new` is just the `String` `"new"`, not the keyword. I edited the answer. Check it out. Hope it is clearer.

Comment: Hm... I'm not sure I follow what you said. Did you understand it or is it still confusing?

Answer (score 0):

Consider following code

```
bikesMap.put("honda","cbr250r");
bikesMap.put("yamaha","yzfr15");

request.setAttribute("bikesMap",bikesMap);
request.setAttribute("company","honda");
```

So if we write `${bikesMap["company"]` then it will not evaluate to `"cbr250r"` because what we are providing in `[]` is a string literal so container will try to find a key `"company"` which is not present. But if we write `${bikesMap[company]}` then this EL will evaulate to `"cbr250r"`.

`${bikesMap[compapny]}` will evaulate to `"cbr250r"` because there is a request attribute named `company` and the value of `company` i.e. `"honda"` is a key to the `bikesMap`.

`${bikesMap["company"]}` will not evaluate to `"cbr250r"` because there is no key named `"company"`.

An advantage of `[]` operator over dot operator is that it can access lists and arrays effectively. You can write `${bikesList["1"]}` but you can't write `${bikesList.1}`.

Hope this helps