# How can I set a session variable in a servlet and get it in a JSP?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, session-variables

I'm learning java and try to pass some variable from servlet to jsp page. Here is code from servlet page

```
@WebServlet("/Welcome")
public class WelcomeServlet extends HttpServlet
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)      throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        session.setAttribute("MyAttribute", "test value");

        // response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp");
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    }

}
```

And simple jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>My Index page</title>
</head>
<body>
Index page
<br />
 <% 
Object sss = request.getAttribute("MyAttribute"); 
String a = "22";

%>

   <%= request.getAttribute("MyAttribute"); %>
</body>
</html>
```

Whatever I do attribete at jsp is null.

What is wrong at this simple code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you are getting if from request not session.

It should be

```
session.getAttribute("MyAttribute")
```

---

I suggest you to use [JavaServer Pages Standard Tag Library](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnakc.html) or [Expression Language](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjddd.html) instead of `Scriplet` that is more easy to use and less error prone.

```
${sessionScope.MyAttribute}
```

or

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>

<c:out value="${sessionScope.MyAttribute}" />
```

you can try `${MyAttribute}`, `${sessionScope['MyAttribute']}` as well.

Read more

- [Oracle Tutorial - Using JSTL](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSTL3.html)
- [Oracle Tutorial - Expression Language](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro7.html)

Comment: There's no need to specify sessionScope in EL in this case.

Comment: why not suggest it. Please explain a bit more.

Comment: And you're not using JSTL, but EL.

Comment: I have added JSTL as well.

Comment: Excause me. Can you explain the different between ${sessionScope.MyAttribute} and ${sessionScope[MyAttribute]} ?

Comment: no difference but there are some limitation when using dot in case of array or groups. Please refer existing posts [#1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17119875/how-to-explain-usages-of-square-brackets-operator-in-el-expressions)  and [#2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18694226/difference-between-dot-operator-and-brackets-in-jsp-el)

Answer (score 4):

You set an attribute in a *session*. You have to retrieve it from a *session*:

```
Object sss = session.getAttribute("MyAttribute");
```

And since you are dispatching the request, you actually don't need a session. You can set the attribute in a request object in your servlet:

```
request.setAttribute("MyAttribute", "test value");
```

Then read it as you are already doing in you JSP.

Comment: you are few seconds late. :)

Comment: @Braj I have to practice typing faster :D

Answer (score 3):

You should avoid scriptlets because they are java code in HTML, they break MVC pattern, they are ugly, odd and deprecated.

Simply replace :

```
<% 
Object sss = request.getAttribute("MyAttribute"); 
String a = "22";

%>
```

with simply using *EL* `${MyAttribute}`

But if you want to stick with scriptlets, you should get the attribute from the proper scope which is `session` in your case.

Comment: You may do some traitment on data, for example : conditional display, loops, etc. Si why not using scriptlet.