# Session are breaking when going to some page

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.7

How can I check weather the session is working or not properly? When I login correctly it's working fine, and also allows me to visit some pages but when going to some other page in same controller it redirects me to the login page. Can anyone suggest the solution.

Comment: you have not set session for other pages. So add session on those pages.  and check the controller is going on that pages or not.

Comment: how can i add session for specific page ?

Comment: please follow this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24222845/how-can-i-set-a-session-variable-in-a-servlet-and-get-it-in-a-jsp