# Session passed to jsp

Tags: jsp, session

This is my servlet page:

```
String email1=(String)session.getAttribute("email");
              out.print(email1);
```

How can I pass this email1 object to JSP files?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I set a session variable in a servlet and get it in a JSP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24222845/how-can-i-set-a-session-variable-in-a-servlet-and-get-it-in-a-jsp)

Answer (score 0):

You can access session attributes in Java Server pages by using Expression Language like so:

```
${sessionScope.<attributeName>}
```

Since you set the attribute name to `email`, you access them like so:

```
${sessionScope.email}
```

If you want to **use the deprecated Scripplets,** just do it like so:

```
<% String email = request.getParameter("email"); %>
```